# play radio stream, in background,ANDROID

Tags: android

HI all,
My app is able to play radio streaming.
But now, i want to implement, background playing option too, i.e, if radio is playing, and user closes the app, the radio should keep on playing,untill user stops it.

Guide me plz.

appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: how you make your application able to play radio streaming??

Comment: Plz how do you make it stream ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out these - https://github.com/avrame/Radio-8-Ball-Android-App

https://github.com/sergeymo/android-radio-t